# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=2 caused by IF condition

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Good day everyone

Im creating application and I need to get some data from text. For this reason i was creating Arraylist, which will be filled up by needed data, was from splitted before string "gh2[]".I was using IF condition to determine required data(gh2[i].matches("[0-9]+]). After filling Array, I was converting Array to a string, by StringBuilder, after this string was splitted.

My problem is when I want to call back for examble second value from splitted String Im getting this error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=2.
I dont understand reason of this error becouse when Im checking, size of the Array is showing 23, when Im calling back string before splitting I can see that is filled up by required data. I was trying to change IF condition like for examble giving negation, then everything is working fine but Array is not filled up by data which I need. Please for advice how to fix this problem. gh2 This my
Here is my program, this is my first program in Android Studio.

```
ArrayList<String> listawynikow = new ArrayList<String>(gh2.length);
for (int i = 0; i < gh2.length; i++) {
  if (gh2[i].matches("[0-9]+")) {
    listawynikow.add(gh2[i]);
  }
}

StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
for (int j = 0; j < listawynikow.size(); j++) {
  sb2.append(listawynikow.get(j)).append(";").append("\n");
}
String wyniki1 = sb2.toString();
String[] WYNIKI = wyniki1.split(";");
```

Comment: We'd need to know exactly which line is causing the ArrayIOOBEx. Is it even a line in the pasted code? Because the pasted code, whilst weird (why gather all data in an array into a list and then into a stringbuilder and then split again? You're running in circles), doesn't seem to have any particular issues. If the AIOOBEx is occurring here, if anything it's `gh2` being changed by another thread.

Comment: please post errorlog

Comment: What I see, if im giving diffent IF condition then "if (gh2[i2].matches("[0-9]+"))" for example Im giving "if (!gh2[i2].matches("[0-9]+"))". I will correct pointless part with creating another String.

Comment: You need to supply more info here, we don't know what line or variable is actually producing the error.

Answer (score 0):

OK, finally I fix the problem by this.

```
for(i2=0; i2<gh2.length;i2++) {
                         listawynikow.add(gh2[i2]); }
                    for(int j2=0; j2<listawynikow.size();j2++){
                        if (!gh2[j2].matches("[0-9]+")){
                            listawynikow.remove(gh2[j2])
```

Thanks everybody for help and fingers crossed for my problem.